# npm install not installing packages

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I've tried to get packages to install by running `npm install discord.js` for example and it doesn't install it.  Below is the terminal.

```
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/-/discord.js-13.1.0.tgz failed, reason: read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

This is after a 5-10 minute wait period.
I've done almost everything imaginable. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!
XRift_0

Edit
After disabling Kaspersky, it worked. How do I make it work with Kaspersky enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Its trying to use the proxy config set in your PC.

Check the .npmrc file available at C:\Users\yourprofile.npmrc.

**Add or remove  the proxy config accordingly or delete the .npmrc**

proxy=http://proxyserveripordn:proxyport/

https-proxy=http://proxyserveripordns:proxyport

http-proxy=http://proxyusername:proxyuserpassword@proxyserveripordns:proxyport

strict-ssl=false

Comment: There wasn't anything in the .npmrc file and it still didn't work after deleting it.

Comment: Are you running from a corporate network where your external web requests are routing via proxy server? In that case you need to add your proxy settings as mentioned. Noted that you are able to run disabling Kaspersky, that means you need to disable Kaspersky running as proxy server.

Comment: I'm on a home PC with no proxy setup.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/`

So that `npm` requests for **http url** instead of **https**.

and after this, try the same `npm install discord.js` command.

Answer (score 0):

This version has been deprecated , now this is no longer in npm

[image: This version has been deprecated]

Comment: That's a typescript version.